# There is no effect on order by - spree_sunspot_search

Tags: solr, spree, sunspot-solr

I have retrieve all products from Solr but order by query is not affected by ascending or descending order.

`http://localhost:3000/products?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keywords=Classic+Chocolate+Cake&order_by=price,desc&commit=Search`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spree, and this is not a native Solr query, but you might try `order_by=price desc` (with a space instead of a comma). The comma would be wrong in Solr, and I doubt it would be different in Spree.

Comment: Spree Sunspot Search looks for an :order_by param for sorting. It must have a value relating to an indexed field and direction comma separated.

        > order_by: 'taxon_ids, asc'